# Is home automation on-topic here?

Tags: support, on-topic, migration, stackexchange

I intend to ask a broad and general question about how to detect presence and position of humans in an indoor environment (my home). I want to know (1) weather there is anyone in the house and (2) in which rooms there are humans.

This fits [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/?as=1), [Electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?as=1), this site (DSP.SE) and probably others (SE-s are popping up like mushrooms lately).

On witch site, if any, is this question appropriate?

Maybe related: [Snore detector](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-to-recognize-patterns-in-a-noisy-audio-frequency-spectrum?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "I intend to ask a broad and general question" → [No, please don't.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)
- "How do I wire this stuff/How do I fix this to the wall" → [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com)
- "How do I design/fix the circuit?" → [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- "How do I detect the signal/track the movement/improve detection/reduce false positives/etc" → [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Even in the last case, you will have to show what you've tried, where you're getting stuck, what algorithm you're trying to improve, etc. Do not use this site as a proxy for "Teach me how to build my own detection system".

Comment: Yeah, I guess I really need to break it up and form concrete questions. Those inter-disciplinary questions really puzzle me as to where should I ask them.